# Is it very dangerous to expose client_secret of Doorkeeper applications in Front End?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, oauth, devise, doorkeeper

My question is if it is very dangerous to have the client_secret in front end (React / React Native), because in all [api endpoints generated by doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/API-endpoint-descriptions-and-examples) you have to put a client_id and client_secret.

If it is dangerous, how can I hide it? I was thinking about overwriting the token controller, something similar to this, but it doesn't work for me, it doesn't recognize the parameters.

```
# app/controllers/token_controller.rb
class TokenController < Doorkeeper::TokensController
  before_action :set_client_key

  private
    def set_client_key
      params[:client_id] = Doorkeeper::Application.find_by(name: "Web client").uid
      params[:client_secret] = Doorkeeper::Application.find_by(name: "Web client").secret
    end
end
```

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users, only: %i[create]
  use_doorkeeper do
    skip_controllers :authorizations, :applications, :authorized_applications
    controllers :tokens => 'token'
  end
  devise_for :users
end
```

The idea is to make a call to the api like the following:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/oauth/token
User-Agent: vscode-restclient
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "client_id": "xxx",
    "grant_type": "password",
    "email": "a@a.a",
    "password": "123456"
}
```

Omitting client_secret so as not to expose it on the client.

The error I get is:

```
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "application_id" violates not-null constraint
```

It is because it does not detect the client_secret.

I configured doorkeeper following [this tutorial](https://rubyyagi.com/rails-api-authentication-devise-doorkeeper/)

Comment: Not passing the secret in the request, or hardcoding it on frontend is just as good. In both scenarios anyone can read your client ID and use it to impersonate your client (call the Authorization Server as your client). You can use a combination of the code flow with Proof-Key for Code Exchange and consent screen in your AS to make sure that your users only log in to your website. I recommend going that way instead of the password flow and hacking OAuth.

Comment: Great, thanks alot!